# rails - how to specify the column to where kt-paperclip gem should calculate the checksum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm using the has_attached_file from paperclip gem to calculate a checksum on the file's content. By default, this calculation will be applied to the column that has the name fingerprint on it but the problem is that I have two columns that must have "fingerprint" in the name.
Is there a way to specify in which column Paperclip should calculate the checksum?

here's what I've tried

```
has_attached_file(
    :file,
{
    hash_digest: Digest::SHA256,
    hash_digest_column: :original_file_fingerprint
 }
)
```

but nothing gets updated.
Any ideas?
https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#checksum--fingerprint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first, there's no problem having multiple columns ending in `_fingerprint`, Paperclip only uses the column named after the attachment, ie. `file_fingerprint` for `has_attached_file :file`.

Second, Paperclip doesn't actually care about columns, it cares about attribute getters/setters, so if you have to conform to some legacy database schema that uses `file_fingerprint` for something else, then you can always just redefine the attribute methods to use a different column.

There are two options depending on whether you still need access to (the actual) `file_fingerprint` from your Rails model.

If you don't need access to it:

```
alias_attribute :file_fingerprint, :original_file_fingerprint
```

If you do (these will not change/alter Rails DB query syntax, like `create`, `update`, `where` clauses etc):

```
def file_fingerprint
  self[:original_file_fingerprint]
end

def file_fingerprint= v
  self[:original_file_fingerprint] = v
end
```